# Freshly created spring boot web app endpoints won't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, gradle

I have used the https://start.spring.io/ to create new Spring Boot app.

This is build.gradle so you can see what i choose at the start.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group = 'temp'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I have created simple endpoint just to see if everything is all right.

```
package controller;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.RequestEntity;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@Controller
//@RequestMapping("github/v1")
public class RepositoriesController {

    @GetMapping
    @CrossOrigin
    public String test(){
        return "yes";
    }

}
```

But whenever i try accesing it either with postman or in the browser I'm gettting 404 Not Found. I Tried to duck around with @RestController, different @GetMapping's anniontions or @RequestMapping before the class as well as @ComponentScan. But nothing seems to work here. I had never had this kind of issue from the get go.

Comment: Replace `@Controller` with `@RestController`. `@Controller` is used for view based applications. Yours will look for a `yes.html` (or whatever view technology you want to use). It doesn't find it hence 404. Next to that you will need something to map to so try `@GetMapping("/github/v1")` (you don't need the toplevel request mapping annotation. Finally make sure that your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class is either in `controller` as a package as well or another top-level package, that being said `controller` isn't really a good package name.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I didn't had my packages at the top level

That's how it should look. Sorry for your time guys.

[image]